# endfloat and \Continuedfloat: incorrect numbering for place holders

Tags: floats, numbering, endfloat

When I use `endfloat` and `\ContinuedFloat`, the table place holders that `endfloat` puts in don't have the correct numbering (while the tables themselves do).  For example if I have a float and another float immediately after with the `\ContinuedFloat` command, they will both be titled Table 1. On the other hand, the place holder in the text will say `[Table 1 about here]` and `[Table 2 about here]`.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `endfloat` package does not support `\ContinuedFloat` you need to correct the corresponding counter by yourself, e.g. by

```
\addtocounter{posttable}{-1}
```

just before the `table` environment containing `\ContinuedFloat`.

Furthermore one can adapt the table replacement text additionally, e.g.:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{caption,endfloat}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Test}
\end{table}

% Variant #1: Just correct the table counter of the `endfloat' package
\addtocounter{posttable}{-1}
\begin{table}
\ContinuedFloat
\caption{Test (cont.)}
\end{table}

% Variant #2: Change the table replacement text additionally
\begingroup % keep changes locally
\addtocounter{posttable}{-1}
\renewcommand\theposttable{\arabic{posttable} (cont.)}
\begin{table}
\ContinuedFloat
\caption{Test (cont.)}
\end{table}
\endgroup

% Variant #3: Remove the table replacement text completely
\begingroup % keep changes locally
\addtocounter{posttable}{-1}
\renewcommand\tableplace{}
\begin{table}
\ContinuedFloat
\caption{Test (cont.)}
\end{table}
\endgroup

% [...]

\end{document}
```

[image]

(`postfigure` and `posttable` are the counters used for the markers replacing the original figures and tables. So the `endfloat` package is using own counters here.)